# How to add ShareActionProvider to onOptionsItemSelected

Tags: android, share

I am new to Android. I would like to add Share function to one of the menu in ActionBar. There are two menus in actionbar which are Share and Info.

```
 @Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();


    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.share) {
        mShareActionProvider = (ShareActionProvider) MenuItemCompat.getActionProvider(item);
        doShare();
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

private void doShare() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    intent.setType("text/plain");
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,"Selected text");
    mShareActionProvider.setShareIntent(intent);
}
```

After I have added line of codes and run application. It returns error Java Null pointer exception.

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example, PID: 1222
java.lang.NullPointerException at com.example.MainActivity.doShare(MainActivity.java:94)
at com.example.MainActivity.onOptionsItemSelected(MainActivity.java:83)
at android.app.Activity.onMenuItemSelected(Activity.java:2617)
```

I have search and found that most of the tutorial in Android teach how to add ShareActionProvider in onCreateOptionsMenu, But I have having two menus in action bar. How to share intent from selected menus in Actionbar?

Comment: Post your stack trace

Comment: @RuchirBaronia, I have added trace, THank you!

Comment: What is your line 83?

Comment: Line 83  -doShare();

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
doShare(mShareActionProvider)

...


private void doShare(ShareActionProvider mShareActionProvider) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    intent.setType("text/plain");
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,"Selected text");
    mShareActionProvider.setShareIntent(intent);
}
```

Comment: @michelletbs Make the method public and try

Comment: its not working too , when i debug, it returns mShareActionProvider=null. Why?

Answer (score -1):

By setting new instance of ShareActionProvider in onCreateOptionsMenu works for me. we use setActionProvider instead of getActionProvider function to share intent.

```
 @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.share);
        share = new ShareActionProvider(this);
        MenuItemCompat.setActionProvider(item, share);

        return(super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu));
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

       //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.share) {
            onShareAction();
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    private void onShareAction() {
        String yourShareText = "test";
        Intent shareIntent = ShareCompat.IntentBuilder.from(this).setType("text/plain").setText(yourShareText).getIntent();
        // Set the share Intent
        if (share != null) {
            share.setShareIntent(shareIntent);
        }
    }
```